# slide() gives me error - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why does this slide() gives the error

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```

**Error: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method**
Thanks
Jean

Comment: What kind of error and what is "this"?

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI in the page?

Comment: Error put in, hmm.. Nick can you put that in the answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include jQuery UI in the page so you have the [`slide` effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/), for example:

- Without jQuery UI, broken: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2x2w/
- With jQuery UI, working: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2x2w/1/

Answer (score 2):

The `hide()` function only accepts two arguments, duration and callback if you are using only the jquery library. Long story short - make sure you have the UI library loaded as well.